# Allow OWA access without allowing logon rights to all servers in domain

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-web-app

I've created a user for a consultant, and configured his account so that it's only allowed to log on to specific servers via the user's properties in the AD Users & Comps tool.

I've included all domain controllers and our mailserver, however when the user attempts to access OWA, they get an HTTP 500 error.

What additional servers would be required besides the mail server and the domain controller for this restricted user to be able to access OWA?